# Configuring Network connection on VMware running ubuntu on WIndow10 host machine

Tags: 14.04, internet, windows-10, connection

I'm running ubuntu in VMware workstation 9, in a windows 10 host machine, But my ubuntu Virtual machine can't access internet connection, How can I configure Ubuntu VM to use the internet connection that windows 10 is using?
Im using `Realtek USB FE Family Controller` driver for Ethernet connection.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Have you made sure that the VM is configured to use NAT for networking?

Comment: No I'm not sure! That's what I want to know

Comment: Go to the virtual machine settings in Workstation and check that the virtual machine networking is set to use NAT.

Comment: yeah it is set to use NAT but still no internet connectio